# what's the requirement for the class parameter in Intent class constructor?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I copied this from Android API reference:

```
public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

for this constructor, I'm curious what is the requirement for the `cls` parameter. I know this usually can be a class extending `Activity` or `Service`, but I'm not sure what's the specific requirement for the class, e.g. the class must extend some class, or this class must have a do() function.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you do with the `Intent` after you construct it.

If you use it in a call to `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()` the class must inherit from `Activity` and it must be declared in an `<activity>` tag in the manifest.

If you use it in a call to `startService()`, `stopService()` or `bindService()` the class must inherit from `Service` and it must be declared in a `<service>` tag in the manifest.

If you use it in a call to `sendBroadcast()` or other similar calls the class must inherit from `BroadcastReceiver` and it must be declared in a `<receiver>` tag in the manifest.

However, there is nothing preventing you from constructing an `Intent` using `new Intent(context, class)` and passing any class you want as the second parameter. The compiler does not check this and the runtime doesn't check either at the time of `Intent` construction.